# Webpack watch mode windows 10

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have tried many times to run webpack in watch mode with --watch flag  but it doest rebundle when a change happend on entry files , here is my config file

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
 entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "dev/App.js"),
 output: {
  path: __dirname,
  filename: 'public/bundle.js'
 },
 module: {
    // configuration regarding modules

    rules: [
      // rules for modules (configure loaders, parser options, etc.)

      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
        ],
        // these are matching conditions, each accepting a regular expression or string
                // conditions for the issuer (the origin of the import)
        loader: "babel-loader",
        // the loader which should be applied, it'll be resolved relative to the context
        // -loader suffix is no longer optional in webpack2 for clarity reasons
        // see webpack 1 upgrade guide

        options: {
          presets: ["es2015","react"]
        },
        // options for the loader
      }]
 },


 resolve: {
   extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
 },

  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 300, // in ms
    // aggregates multiple changes to a single rebuild
    poll: 300, // intervall in ms
    // enables polling mode for watching
    // must be used on filesystems that doesn't notify on change
    // i. e. nfs shares
  }

};﻿
```

same config file works on Linux very well , but i dont know why it doesnt work on Windows 10 64bit, by the way the webpack versions that i used v2.2.0 , v2.2.1 , v1.13.1 , and some others i dont remember , none of them works :S